# How can I get configfile to access minikube from outside cluster to create pods, delete pods, etc

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, devops, minikube

I am trying to setup Airflow to use an external k8s cluster, in local it is minikube, as executor. To do that I need to point Airflow to a kubernetes configfile that contains the necessary information to alow external resources to request and schedule resources on the cluster, but for minikube I am not able to get, generate or know how to write that file, can anyone point me to some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running Airflow inside a K8S cluster (minikube or remote cluster), you don't need a `configfile` to access K8S API. You can configure the kubernetes connection to use the in_cluster option:

```py
AIRFLOW_CONN_KUBERNETES_DEFAULT=kubernetes://?extra__kubernetes__in_cluster=True&conn_id=kubernetes_default
```

If your are running Airflow in docker or directly in you host, and you want to access minikube to test `KubernetesPodOperator`, you can provide the config file by setting the config `AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES__CONFIG_FILE`.
For the minikube config file, it's auto generated in `~/.kube/config` but merged with the other config files, you can copy it to a new files, and remove the info of the other cluster and contexts (if you have other cluster). If you don't find the minikube config, or you just want to regenerate a new one:

```bash
export KUBECONFIG=<path where you want to create it>
minikube start
```

Once minikube is up, you can find the config file in the folder you provided.

Comment: Hi, I continue cheking on this but now my scheduler is not able to connect to minikube, I added it to minikube network, and in the config file I settled `    server:http://minikube:5000 but I always get an error and scheduler does not connect. should I use another port or host?